# Unity events in animation missing

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to use Events in my animation ( my animation is part of my .fbx file which is exported from 3d studio nad I imported to Unity 5.3 ) to change behavior of my character like in http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-AnimationEvents.html 
but I don't have Events option like in tutorial and when I click double on any moment in timeline no new event is created.

How to add Events option to animation ( I know how to add callbacks once I have option for events from previous tutorial  )

[image]

Comment: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationEventsOnImportedClips.html .. click "animations" tab up top ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Animation events have to be added in the "Animation" window (not "Animator"). Open it, then select a GameObject which has the AnimationClip you want to add events to (can either be GameObject with an Animator or with an Animation component).

You should now be able to select the clip in the Animation window and add events to it by right-clicking in the dark grey section right below the timeline.

Comment: One important side-note is that the AnimationEvent will display a set of public methods from script that ARE ATTACHED TO THE GAME OBJECT. It is not like any UnityEvent where you can drag and drop any object in the slot. This system requires the script to be on the object that holds the Animator component.

Comment: hey @thomas, i added a image from my comment under the answer - is that the right one?

Comment: unfortunately not ^^ I'm talking about the Animation **window**, not tab. You open it through the menu: Window -> Animation.

Comment: ok it would be great if you added a screenshot, to your great answer.  this will be the "canonical" answer to this question you know?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the "Rig" tab of the object and select "Generic". It's probably set to Legacy, which won't give you the events option.