# Triggering an animation from a script related to the value of a slider

Tags: c#, animation, slider, unity-game-engine

I have a script that gives me the normalized value of a slider which is set to `animationTime`

Along this slider I'd like some little pop ups to appear to indicate important dates to the user when they happen, but just having them 'appear' is super boring and doesn't catch the eye, so I'd like a little toast like pop-up animation to happen.

How do I trigger this animation upon reaching the correct point on the slider?

So far to just get them to appear I'm using this script.

```
    float t = animationTime;
    if (0.256f < t)
    {
        pilingFinished.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
    else
    {
        pilingFinished.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    if (0.39f < t)
    {
        basementFinished.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
    else
    {
        basementFinished.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

From my limited knowledge I'm sure this can be cleaned up as well, considering there are going to be multiple toast pop-ups on the timeline to indicate many different important dates to be looking at.

Many thanks

Comment: in the first instance, you almost certainly have to learn everything there is to know about animation "events" .  they trigger a call in your code.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/35677578/294884

Comment: your code, as such , would look more like this: you need a ***BETWEEN*** concept right?  you write "betweens" exactly like this:  `if (0.13f < t && t < 0.14f)`    if ( BLAH < t && t < BLAH ).  Notice you use two "<" signs and the t "stays near the middle" of the two limits.

Comment: So I use a between concept for the animation, and then a normal < for the icon to appear there after the animation has taken place, as I'm using the animation as an entry animation. Does this make sense?

Comment: I would stick with "BETWEEN", so if you think about it in that case it would be "between 0f and .1f" .. you know ?!  hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

There's a fair amount of setup to this solution, but it's all relatively simple logic. I'm using two classes, owe that automatically positions the elements along the slider and handles the `OnChange` event of the slider, and the other which controls the animator of the element.

**TimelineController.cs**

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Slider))]
public class TimelineController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private RectTransform       m_transform;
    private Slider              m_slider;
    private TimelineElement[]   m_elements;
    private Vector3             m_tempPosition;

    public void Start()
    {
        m_transform         = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        m_slider            = GetComponent<Slider>();
        m_elements          = GetComponentsInChildren<TimelineElement>();
        m_slider.maxValue   = m_elements.Length - 1;
        m_tempPosition      = m_elements[0].GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition;

        for(int element = 0; element < m_elements.Length; element++)
        {
            m_tempPosition.x = (m_transform.rect.width - 20f) * ((float)element / (m_elements.Length - 1));
            Debug.Log(m_transform.rect.width);
            m_elements[element].GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition = m_tempPosition;
        }

        m_elements[0].SetVisible(true);
    }

    public void OnChange()
    {
        m_elements[(int)m_slider.value].SetVisible(true);

        for (int element = 0; element < m_elements.Length; element++)
        {
            if (element != (int)m_slider.value)
                m_elements[element].SetVisible(false);
        }
    }
}
```

To position all the elements, the number of TimelineElement components in the children is got, the slider's maxValue is set to the number of elements retrieved, and an initial Vector3 of the element is got.

```
(m_transform.rect.width - 20f) * ((float)element / (m_elements.Length - 1));
```

Each position is determined based on a percentage (current element divided by the length of the element array), and multiplying this by the width of the slider minus 20f (the width of the handle).

**TimelineElement.cs**

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Animator))]
public class TimelineElement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Animator m_animator;

    public void Start()
    {
        m_animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    public void SetVisible(bool p_visible)
    {
        m_animator.SetBool("Visible", p_visible);
    }
}
```

As previously described, this simple sets a boolean in the animator to true or false, causing the relevant animation to play. All that's left is to setup your hierarchy similar to the example above with a bool `Visible` in the animator, and set your slider `Whole Numbers` to `true`.

Hope this helped.

Comment: This looks amazing, I'll give this a go at some point this week, thanks for taking the time to write all of this for me.